# ggfortify autoplot confidence intervals level

Tags: r, ggplot2, xts, forecast, ggfortify

I am trying to estimate 95% confidence intervals using autoplot from ggfortify, however I am not able to achieve it. If I use the forecast package and forecast ahead 3 weeks with 95% CI it works fine. See below:

```
wt <- structure(list(DOC = c(3, 10, 17, 24, 31, 38, 45, 52, 59, 66, 
73, 80, 87, 94, 101), AvgWeight = c(1, 1.66666666666667, 2.06666666666667, 
2.275, 3.83333333333333, 6.2, 7.4, 8.5, 10.25, 11.1, 13.625, 
15.2, 16.375, 17.8, 21.5), PondName = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Pond01", class = "factor"), 
    SampleDate = structure(c(1182585600, 1183190400, 1183795200, 
    1184400000, 1185004800, 1185609600, 1186214400, 1186819200, 
    1187424000, 1188028800, 1188633600, 1189238400, 1189843200, 
    1190448000, 1191052800), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"))), .Names = c("DOC", 
"AvgWeight", "PondName", "SampleDate"), row.names = c(NA, 15L
), class = "data.frame")  

wt$SampleDate <- as.Date(wt$SampleDate)  
wt
     DOC AvgWeight PondName SampleDate
1    3  1.000000   Pond01 2007-06-23
2   10  1.666667   Pond01 2007-06-30
3   17  2.066667   Pond01 2007-07-07
4   24  2.275000   Pond01 2007-07-14
5   31  3.833333   Pond01 2007-07-21
6   38  6.200000   Pond01 2007-07-28
7   45  7.400000   Pond01 2007-08-04
8   52  8.500000   Pond01 2007-08-11
9   59 10.250000   Pond01 2007-08-18
10  66 11.100000   Pond01 2007-08-25
11  73 13.625000   Pond01 2007-09-01
12  80 15.200000   Pond01 2007-09-08
13  87 16.375000   Pond01 2007-09-15
14  94 17.800000   Pond01 2007-09-22
15 101 21.500000   Pond01 2007-09-29

    library(forecast)
    library(ggfortify)
    library(ggplot2)
    library(xts) 

pond <- as.xts(wt$AvgWeight,order.by=seq(as.Date("2007-06-23"), by=7, len=15))
pond 
d.arima <- auto.arima(pond)
d.arima;fitted(d.arima)
d.forecast <- forecast(d.arima, level = c(95), h = 3)
d.forecast


 > d.forecast
    Point Forecast    Lo 95    Hi 95
106           25.2 23.14483 27.25517
113           28.9 24.30450 33.49550
120           32.6 24.91026 40.28974
```

I get the correct 95% confidence intervals when I plot a forecast package object (d.forecast in this case)

```
autoplot(d.forecast,ts.colour='dodgerblue',predict.colour='green',
predict.linetype='dashed',ts.size=1.5,conf.int.fill='azure3') +
 xlab('DOC') + ylab('AvgWeight-grs') + theme_bw()
```

[image]

But if I do:

```
ggfortify::autoplot(d.arima,predict=predict(d.arima,n.ahead=3),conf.int=TRUE,predict.alpha = 
0.05,fitted.colour="green",
predict.colour='red',predict.linetype='solid')
```

[image]

It defaults to 80% confidence intervals. I tried to set the level of confidence inside predict() but it gets ignored. I also tried the level inside autoplot() and also did not work. Questions: How can I accomplish different levels of confidence using autoplot from ggfortify? Is it correct to use predict.alpha here or it is intended for the alpha color of the predicted point estimate?
Also, is it possible to connect the fitted green line to the predicted red line?

Comment: I cannot reproduce on `ggfortify_0.4.7` and `forecast_8.10`. `ggfortify::autoplot(...)` throws an error, see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm surprised you're not getting an error and are seeing the plots you're showing. Unfortunately I cannot reproduce your plots

1. When I load `ggfortify` *after* `forecast`, I couldn't find a way to use `forecast`s `autoplot`. That's because `ggfortify` does not actually export `autoplot`; instead it overwrites the `autoplot` method from `forecast`. So `ggfortify::autoplot(...)` shouldn't work, and should throw the error

   > Error: 'autoplot' is not an exported object from 'namespace:ggfortify'
2. There is also no `predict` argument of `autoplot.forecast` or `autoplot.ts`, so I'm not sure where that comes from.

Is there a reason why you want to use `forecast` *and* `ggfortify`? Why not stick with `forecast`s `autoplot` for plotting? Here is an example based on your sample data and `d.arima`

```r
autoplot(forecast(d.arima)) + theme_minimal()
```

[image]

The light and dark areas correspond to the 95% and 80% CIs, respectively.

Tested using `forecast_8.10` and `ggfortify_0.4.7`.

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will stick with forecast. The reason I wanted to use ggfortify is because autoplot seems to have more options to prettify the plot. for example ggfortify connects the predicted values to the original values and also allows you to draw a ribbon around the confidence intervals. Maybe autoplot from forecast does too have those options? I will check it out. Thanks